# How to create a sequence of clicks in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am creating a puzzle in which the player have to click on the buttons on the right order or sequence to go to the next level (Scene 2 for example). I don't know how to do it. If any one have any idea to how to achieve this in Action Script.

Thank you

Scene 1:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1IYZ.png)

each number is a button. Now the player has to click in the right order or sequence (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) to open the next level (Scene 2)

```
var checkString:String = "";

//Create event listeners and their functions.
btn1.addEventListener(Mouse.CLICK, oneClick);
btn2.addEventListener(Mouse.CLICK, twoClick);
btn3.addEventListener(Mouse.CLICK, threeClick);
btn4.addEventListener(Mouse.CLICK, fourClick);
btn5.addEventListener(Mouse.CLICK, fiveClick);
btn6.addEventListener(Mouse.CLICK, sixClick);
btn7.addEventListener(Mouse.CLICK, sevenClick);
btn8.addEventListener(Mouse.CLICK, eightClick);


function oneClick(evt:Event):void
{
   //In each event listener function, add a letter or 
   //string to the checkString variable.
   checkString += "on";

   //Then, see if the string matches or not.
   check();
}

function twoClick(evt:Event):void
{
   checkString += "tw";
   check();
}

function threeClick(evt:Event):void
{
   checkString += "th";
   check();
}

function fourClick(evt:Event):void
{
   checkString += "fo";
   check();
}

function fiveClick(evt:Event):void
{
   checkString += "fi";
   check();
}

function sixClick(evt:Event):void
{
   checkString += "si";
   check();
}

function sevenClick(evt:Event):void
{
   checkString += "se";
   check();
}

function eightClick(evt:Event):void
{
   checkString += "ei";
   check();
}



//If the proper sequence is one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight the string would read "ontwthfofisiseei".
function check():void
{
   if(checkString == "ontwthfofisiseei")
   {
      //Clear the checkString for convenience before going on.
      clearString();
      //CODE TO GO TO NEW FRAME

gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 3");
   }

}

function clearString():void
{
   //You will want to have a function for clearing the string.
   //This is especially useful if you have a button for "start over."
   checkString = "";
}
```

this the code i used before but it show error in the listener and it doesn't. work

Comment: Please share your existing relevant code.

Comment: What error? What listener?

Comment: @KyleDelaney in the event listener

Comment: Your error is likely that `Mouse.CLICK` should be `MouseEvent.CLICK`

Comment: Good catch @BadFeelingAboutThis. I'm amazed I didn't notice that.

Comment: I fixed it but it gives me this error message ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene Scene 3 was not found.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
 at level1_Scene2_fla::MainTimeline/check()
 at level1_Scene2_fla::MainTimeline/eightClick()

Comment: That error is saying that there is no "Scene 3" found.  So double check what your scenes are called and how many you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your updated question:

Your error is likely that `Mouse.CLICK` should be `MouseEvent.CLICK`.

Your other error is telling you that there is no scene called `"Scene 3"`

---

Let's assume you have 8 MovieClips (or buttons) that are on a timeline in Flash/Animate.

One (of many) ways to accomplish this would be the following:

1. Give each of those buttons an instance name.   To make for less code, lets give them the name `btn` + their respective correct order number - so `btn1`, `btn2`, `btn3` etc.
2. You'll need to add a click listener to each button, so they can have something happen when they are clicked.

   You could do this 8 times (one for each button):  `btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick);` but to make things simpler, you can just iterate through all the objects on the timeline and add the listener to each object whose name starts with "btn":

   ```
   var totalBtns:int = 0; //create a var to store how many buttons there are
   //loop through each child of the current timeline
   var i:int = numChildren;
   while(i--){
       //if the child's name starts with 'btn'
       if(getChildAt(i).name.indexOf("btn") == 0){
           //add the click listener
           getChildAt(i).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick,false,0,true);
           totalBtns++; //increase the total buttons variable by 1
       }
   }
   ```

   This also means less work later if you add/remove buttons
3. You need a way to track when a button was clicked.  To accomplish this, we'll use an array.

   ```
   var clickArray:Array = []; //this creates a new array
   //When a button is clicked, you add it to this array
   ```
4. lets create the function that is called when a button is clicked:

   ```
   function buttonClick(e:Event):void {
       //add the item that was just clicked (represented by the event's currentTarget property) to the array
       //so if btn1 was just clicked, btn1 would be e.currentTarget
       clickArray.push(e.currentTarget);

       //now disable the button so it can't be clicked anymore
       SimpleButton(e.currentTarget).enabled = false;

       //check if all button have been clicked
       if(clickArray.length == totalBtns){

          //lets go through every item in the array, and see if it's in the right order
          var ctr:int = 0; //a counter to keep track of the expected next number         var i:int = 0; //iterator for the for loops
          for(i=0;i<clickArray.length;i++){
              //lets convert everything after the 3rd character of the name to a number - so for btn1, that would be 1
              if(parseInt(clickArray[i].name.substring(3)) == ctr + 1){
                 ctr++; //increment the counter to the next expected number
              }else{
                 break; //leave the for loop early since a click was out of place
              }
          }

          //if the correct order was achieved
          if(ctr == totalBtns){
              nextScene(); //or however you continue
          }else{
              //the correct order was NOT acheived

              //make all the buttons clickable again
              for(i=0;i<clickArray.length;i++){
                  SimpleButton(clickArray[i]).enabled = true;
              }

              //reset the array
              clickArray = [];

              //probably want to tell the user to try again
          }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: It gives me this error 'TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::SimpleButton@3db880ec791 to flash.display.Sprite.
 at level1_Scene2_fla::MainTimeline/buttonClick()'

Comment: I've updated the answer for use with SimpleButton's instead of MovieClips

Comment: I just tested it and it works.  Perhaps your issue lies elsewhere?  Are you mixing this example of mine with your original code?   What error are you getting?

Comment: No i did not mix them together. The problem is in moving to next scene if the sequence is correct. It does not give an error message but it also does not move to next scene when i following the correct sequence.

Comment: Try this:  where in my code it has the line `nextScene()`,  right above it, put:  `trace("YOU DID IT!!!!");`.  Run the program and see if you get that trace message in the output window after you click all the buttons in the correct order - that will let you know if the problem is moving on to the next scene, or calculating the correctness of answers

Comment: Also, make sure you have another scene.  I see you posted an error that indicates flash doesn't think you have a "scene 3".